# Integration of Google Custom Search in Clojure project running on server

Tags: java, json, clojure, server, google-search-api

I working on a clojure project for a web application (a chatbot). I integrated a Google Custom Search with the ["Custom JSON API Reference"](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/json-api/v1/overview)  tool in the cases in which the chatbot hasn't a answer to a question, the google search results are pretty printed in the chat window. On the local host everything works fine but online (while running the compiled jar file on server) nothing happens if a question is asked for which the chatbot has no answer. Does anyone know the problem?

My project dependencies are in project.clj:

```
  :dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.6.0"]
                [compojure "1.1.7"]
                [hiccup "1.0.2"]
                [org.clojure/java.jdbc "0.2.3"]
                [ring/ring-jetty-adapter "1.2.1"]
                [com.h2database/h2 "1.3.170"]
                [cheshire "5.5.0"] ;
                [org.clojure/clojurescript "0.0-2371"]
                [clj-http "2.0.0"]]
```

And in the file in which the Google Custom Search is integrated I use the REST in the JSON Custom Search API for receiving the results with the clj-http.client get-function.

The match.clj file contains:

```
   (:require ...
             [clj-http.client :as client]
             [clojure.data.json :as json]
             [clojure.pprint :as pprint]
             [cheshire.core :refer :all]
    )
```

And calls the function:

```
(client/get (str google-search-url (apply str question)))
```

Where the google-search-url has this form:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?key=(put in API key)&cx=(put in Engine ID)
```

I don't understand why this works if running the jar file on the local host and fails if running on the server. First, I generated a browser key, but I then read there are also server API keys and tried it again with this one. Nevertheless, it doesn't work, yet.

I looking forward for someone who can help me!

The problem is not resolved, yet. I logged the errors on the server and I got this:

Jan 28, 2016 4:58:21 PM org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec execute
INFO: I/O exception (java.net.SocketException) caught when processing request to {s}->https://clojars.org:443: Das Netzwerk ist nicht erreichbar

Knows someone what could be the reason???

Comment: No stacktraces in the server logs?

Comment: I'd add an NREPL server and debug from there...

Comment: I get this: Jan 28, 2016 5:02:35 PM org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec execute
INFO: Retrying request to {s}->https://clojars.org:443 I have no idea how to fix this?!

Comment: Thank you for your comments!

Comment: The problem is not resolved, yet. I logged the errors on the server and I got this:

Jan 28, 2016 4:58:21 PM org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec execute
INFO: I/O exception (java.net.SocketException) caught when processing request to {s}->https://clojars.org:443: Das Netzwerk ist nicht erreichbar
Jan 28, 2016 4:58:21 PM org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec execute
INFO: Retrying request to {s}->https://clojars.org:443

Knows someone what could be the reason???